# Check if time is in between two time slot

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

**Let's say working slot is like : 10:00 AM to 07:30 PM**

**Now user enter time like 01:00 PM so it should accept it but if user enter time like 10:00 PM then it should not accept.**

I am getting time in working slots from database and converting them in timespan as per below :

```
startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(startTime24);
endTime = TimeSpan.Parse(endTime24);
```

Now I will get time from user side and assigning it to one variable and it will contain time, so now I want to check if that time is within this time slot or not.

Below is code,   I have tried code to check if user's time is between slot or not, but not working as expected..any idea

```
startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(startTime24); // This is starting time from working slot
endTime = TimeSpan.Parse(endTime24); // // This is ending time from working slot

TimeSpan appointmentTimeSpan = obj.AppointmentTimeFrom // This is time I am getting from user.

if (appointmentTimeSpan > startTime && appointmentTimeSpan < endTime)
{
    return Messages.WorkingSlotNotAvailable;
}
```

Comment: Can the working slots span across midnight? And can you give some concrete examples? You say it's not working as expected, the issue is that we don't know the values and what you expect it to do, so can you make a concrete example with some actual values?

Comment: The comparison operators for `TimeSpan` are just comparing the length of time, I'm not sure how you would use `TimeSpan` in the way you have posted.  Are those supposed to be `DateTime`?  Is the idea that you want to see if the duration of an appointment falls completely between two times?

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to compare. A `TimeSpan` object is a “span” of time, with total days, hours, minutes etc… however there is no particular “date” associated with the time span. So when you compare two `TimeSpan` objects like `ts1 > ts2` is simply comparing if `ts1`’s amount of the time span is greater than the `ts2`’s amount of time span. So when you say that you want… _”to check if user's time is between slot”_ … ? … I am not really understating what you mean.

Comment: I have edited question with example @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: @JohnG I have used timespan just to compare..but it does not worked..so I am thinking for other option to use

Comment: it's a bit like asking if 3 cm line will fit between GPS point A and GPS point B. It depends where that 3cm line will start. That information is missing here. Please use DateTime objects.

Comment: @Nic show us the exact content and type of `startTime24` and `endTime24` - there isn't really anything wrong with your logic of using 3 timespans as points in time for comparitive purposes, so long as your 1pm and 730pm are 13h00m00s and 19h30m00s respectively, and your end time is after your start time..

Comment: After further review and testing, I agree with Caius Jard, comparing the `TimeSpans` should still work as you have shown… is what is odd from my point of view is that in the `if` condition you have… `if (appointmentTimeSpan > startTime && appointmentTimeSpan < endTime)` … and if both conditions are `true` then the `appointmentTimeSpan` would INDEED fall between the start and end time. Yet the returned message is “WorkingSlotNotAvailable” this seems backwards to me.

Comment: Does `TimeSpan.Parse(...)` actually parse stuff, or does it crash? I still don't understand what you mean by it not working. To be blunt, a TimeSpan, if you consider it to be a time-of-day, should work just fine. It's not AM/PM problematic, it should handle a 24-hour clock just fine.